# Can every tree with total length $2$ be covered by a semi-disc of radius $1$?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, combinatorial-geometry

Can every tree with total length $2$ be covered by a semi-disc of radius $1$?

If the tree is actually a curve, or the convex hull of the tree is a triangle, I know this is correct after some attempts. But for the general case, I have no idea.

Comment: By semi-disc, do you mean [this shape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semicircle)?

Comment: I think I know what you are asking, but what exactly do you mean by tree and total length? Do you mean a collection of curves in the plane, whose lengths sum to 2, that forms a loopless connected plane set?

Comment: @RavenclawPrefect Yes.

Comment: @BrandonduPreez You are right. What I mean exactly is a set of points and segments between them. The set of segments form a tree, and the sum of length is 2.

Comment: This is a really nasty problem! The issue is that there are cases of locally optimal semicircles of radius greater than 1, that are not globally optimal...